# Accessibility between Action and Delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

In the code below I created a delegate named `Mhd` - just like the `Action` delegate.
**My question:** if the two delegates are **public**, why only `Action` delegate is visible from another class and not `Mhd`?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Test().Yaser(); //this can be done
        new Test().mhd(); //this can not be done
    }
    class Test
    {
        public Action Yaser;
        public delegate void Mhd();
    }

    //and Action definition is   public delegate void Action();
```

any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my answer to make sense, it's important to remember the definition of a delegate. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A delegate is a reference type that can be used to encapsulate a named or an anonymous method.

A delegate is a **reference**?!?!

If you are familiar with C++, you know that another way of saying ***reference*** is ***pointer***. (In fact, C++ developers get *similar* functionality to C# delegates via function pointers.)

What is the significance of delegates being references? Among the basic constructs provided by the common type system, the .NET Framework has another reference type: `class`. Saying that a delegate is a reference type is just like saying that **a delegate is a class**. Let's review how we use classes.

There are 3 steps you need to follow before you can use an instance of a class:

- Type declaration:     `class Test { public Action Yaser; }`
- Instance declaration: `class Test testClassObject;`
- Instantiation:        `testClassObject = new Test();`

(Typically, we combine instance declaration and instantiation).

We said that delegates are classes. Therefore, delegate use follows the same pattern:

- Type declaration: `public delegate void Mhd();`
- Instance declaration: `public Mhd myMhd;`
- Instantiation: `myDelegateField = new Mhd(SomeMethod);`

But wait, what is `SomeMethod`? Truly, it doesn't matter. All that we know is that its signature must match that of Mhd. In other words, `void SomeMethod()`

Let's inspect and fix your class declaration. A possible implementation is shown below:

```
class Test
{
    public Action Yaser;        // instance declaration
    public delegate void Mhd(); // type declaration
    public Mhd myMhd;           // instance declaration

    public Test()
    {
        // instantiation
        this.myMhd = new Mhd(this.SomeMethod);
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        // your implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but 
Instantiation must be myMhd = new Mhd(SomeMethod); right?

Comment: Yep, it was shown in the delegate bullets, but I've edited the class to make the example complete :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Action Yaser;
```

declares a field of type `Action`, whereas

```
    public delegate void Mhd();
```

declares the `Mhd` as delegate type.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Mhd` is not a member of your class. It's a *delegate* type that you declared in your class.

So you can't treat it like a member method or property but you can use it to declare a variable of that type

```
Test.Mhd myDelegate;
```