# Difference between Action and delegate instantiation and accessibility

Tags: c#, delegates, action

Why is MyDeler "static", as in I can access MyDeler through the class name, but I can't explicity say public "static" delegate void MyDeler(), nor can I access d through an instance of MyClass, as in new MyClass.d()?

Further, why is it that I have to new up a MyClass to use MyVoidAction?

See code below:

```
using System;

public class MyClass
{
    public delegate void MyDeler();
    public Action MyVoidAction;
}

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass.MyDeler d = () => Console.WriteLine("my deler");
        d();
        // MyClass.MyVoidAction mva1 = () => Console.WriteLine("my void action"); // not allowed, why?
        MyClass meClass = new MyClass();
        meClass.MyVoidAction = () => Console.WriteLine("my void action");
        meClass.MyVoidAction();
    }
}
```

I looked up this answer: [Accessibility between Action and Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117227/accessibility-between-action-and-delegate)

That cleared up a lot, but I'm not sure I'm 100% on this. So according to that answer, the delegate void MyDeler() defines a type, which confuses me because I imagine something like this:

```
using System;

class MainClass
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public static class DelegateClass
        {
            public void DoDel() // isn't even legal?
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DoDel()");
            }
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        //MyClass.DelegateClass d = new asdf // ??? something like this?
    }
}
```

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's demystify this:

When you declare `MyDeler`:

```
public delegate void MyDeler();
```

What you are doing is defining a type of method to which execution will be "delegated". In other words, you are saying there is method out there that follows this signature and I intend to keep references to it. In order for the compiler to identify these references, this type will be used.

It follows then that you will need to actually have a real pointer to the method, since this is just your "definition". That's why you will need a variable of type "MyDeler" to which you can assign the actual method to call:

```
MyClass.MyDeler d = () => Console.WriteLine("my deler");
```

This line is saying "create a variable named `d` of type `MyClass.MyDeler` that holds a reference to this inline method". From here on, when you call `d();` the pointer will actually execute the inline method.

For the action:

```
public Action MyVoidAction;
```

You are now declaring a public **property** of the class. Therefore, you need an instance of the class before you can use this property.

The trick here is that Action is a known definition of a delegate. Microsoft has a built-in type that you can use instead of declaring your own `void MyDeler();`. It's essentially syntactical sugar but remember, it's still a type and as you have created a public property, you now need to assign it the method that will actually execute and as we discussed before, you need an instance:

```
MyClass meClass = new MyClass(); //Instance creation
meClass.MyVoidAction = () => Console.WriteLine("my void action"); //Tell your delegate what to delegate to.
meClass.MyVoidAction(); //Run the inline method!
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`MyDeler` is a *type* declaration, not a variable declaration.  You can't store things in it or assign to it.

To create a field for storing a `MyDeler` instance, add this line to `MyClass`:

```
public MyDeler MyDelerField;
```

Now you can assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is MyDeler "static", as in I can access MyDeler through the class name, but I can't explicity say public "static" delegate void MyDeler(), nor can I access d through an instance of MyClass, as in new MyClass.d()?

The declaration of `MyDeler` declares a *type* within `MyClass`. It's similar to declaring any other nested type, like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public class MyNestedClass { }
}
```

It is a member of the *type* `MyClass`, not of any actual instance of `MyClass`, nor even of the class `MyClass` as a `static` member would be.

A nested type is neither "instance" nor "static", because it's part of the *type system*, not part of the class itself.

> why is it that I have to new up a MyClass to use MyVoidAction?

Because `MyVoidAction` *is* a member of the class, and is an *instance* member. So you are required to have an *instance* of the class to access it.

> the delegate void MyDeler() defines a type, which confuses me because I imagine something like this

Your declaration in that example of `public static class DelegateClass` is doing something completely different. An unfortunate aspect of C# is the use of `static` to refer to a variety of different things. It's not quite as bad as in Java, but it can still be confusing (as you're finding out).

In that declaration, the use of the word `static` does *not* make `DelegateClass` a "static member" of the containing type `MyClass`. Instead, the word `static` as part of a `class` declaration means that the *entire class* will contain only `static` members.

Thus, when you declare `DoDel()` without the `static` keyword, you are attempting to declare an instance member, i.e. that method, in a class where you've promised to declare only static members. If you add `static` to the method declaration, it would compile.

Not that doing so would make the `DelegateClass` class in that example similar to the `MyVoidAction` member in your other example. It's still a *type* declaration, declaring a nested type within the `MyClass` class, and would still follow the rules for types, not class members. But I hope that at least explains to you why the example that's confusing you works the way it does.

Comment: Ah, that really tickles my brain. I was previously unfamiliar with nested classes.

Answer (score 0):

`Action` and a `delegate` of a method with no parameters and that returns `void` are formally the same thing.

If u take a look to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action(v=vs.110).aspx you can see that:

> You can use this delegate to pass a method as a parameter without
>   explicitly declaring a custom delegate.

I hope this example helps:

```
public delegate void DelegateMyDeler(); //This is a custom delegate

public class MyClass
{
    public DelegateMyDeler MyDeler; //This use your custom delegate
    public Action MyVoidAction; // This use Action delegate
}

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // MyClass.MyDeler d = () => Console.WriteLine("my deler"); // Now this is not allowed too!
        // d();
        //  MyClass.MyVoidAction mva1 = () => Console.WriteLine("my void action"); // not allowed, why?
        MyClass meClass = new MyClass();

        meClass.MyDeler = () => Console.WriteLine("my deler");
        meClass.MyDeler();

        meClass.MyVoidAction = () => Console.WriteLine("my void action");
        meClass.MyVoidAction();

        //but you can do (you custom delegate is defined out of the class in this case
        //so you have not to add the class prefix):
        DelegateMyDeler d = () => Console.WriteLine("my deler 2");
        d();

        // or
        DelegateMyDeler d3 = () => Console.WriteLine("my deler 3");
        d3.Invoke();

        // and in a real case, for example:
        DelegateMyDeler undeterminedMethod;

        int x = 3;
        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:
                undeterminedMethod = deler1;
                break;
            case 2:
                undeterminedMethod = deler2;
                break;
            case 3:
                undeterminedMethod = deler3;
                break;
            default:
                undeterminedMethod = null;
                break;
        }

        undeterminedMethod?.Invoke(); //In case x is minor than 1 or major than 3, nothing happens

    }

    static void deler1() { Console.WriteLine("my deler 1"); }
    static void deler2() { Console.WriteLine("my deler 2"); }
    static void deler3() { Console.WriteLine("my deler 3"); }
}
```